# Gatsby v2 site does not load CSS properly

Tags: css, build, gatsby

In my dev environment the site looks as expected, however when I run gatsby build my CSS does not display properly. If I manually navigate to another page then the CSS displays as expected.

There are no errors but I do get this warning:

> The resource
>   http://localhost:9000/static/d/520/path---offline-plugin-app-shell-fallback-a-30-c5a-NZuapzHg3X9TaN1iIixfv1W23E.json
>   was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds
>   from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate
>   `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.

When I inspect that file it shows:

```
{"pageContext":{}}
```

The fact that that object is empty is my issue I assume. I have tried disabling the service worker but that only made the issue worse.

I've also tried

- forcing a build and disabling the cache on netlify,
- deleting npm and package.json files and then running npm build,

but no luck so far.

Answer (score 7):

This could be related to the fact that main component e.g Layout unmounts and remounts on every page.

Try to refer your css files in `gatsby-browser.js` file which is provided by default and is located in the root of your project.

For example you could try do following:

```
// gatsby-browser.js
require('./my-global-styles.css')
```

It'll also work with `gatsby-plugin-sass`

```
// gatsby-browser.js
import './src/styles/my-global-styles.scss'
```

For more info visit: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/browser-apis/

Answer (score 5):

I have the same issue. In my case, `gatsby-plugin-styled-components` was missing in my `gatsby-config.js`.

https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-styled-components/

https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/8984

Comment: I have had this suggested in other forums, but I was not having this issue. I rebuilt my site step by step and found that it had to do with media queries in conjunction with emotion or styled components. I was not able to pin it down exactly which is why I have not provided an answer.