# How does gatsby.js render CSS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I'm using gatsby.js with a styled component to develop my portfolio and when it doesn't render any CSS when I load my site the first time. However, it renders all CSS correctly when I refresh the page. What could be the reason?
This is my portfolio: https://haribhandari.me

The first time you open the link, the CSS will not load, however, if you refresh it will.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When using styled components, Gatsby on production may not render styles correctly. To fix that, follow those instructions:

1. Install following packages:

```
npm install gatsby-plugin-styled-components styled-components
   babel-plugin-styled-components
```

2. Edit the **gatsby-config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-styled-components`,
      options: {
        // Add any options here
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

More information are described in the [documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-styled-components/)

Answer (score -2):

A great way to let other's help you out is to provide some code snippets as it is hard to go through your site's code just in the browser tools.

I am not a gatsby expert and hope someone can help you understand the concept better. I would look into your `<head>` section.

```
<link as="script" rel="preload" href="/component---cache-caches-gatsby-plugin-offline-app-shell-js-ad6431e4664bcf916d19.js">
```

There is a similar topic regarding this issue here [Gatsby v2 site does not load CSS properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52613354/gatsby-v2-site-does-not-load-css-properly)

I also notice that your menu does not scroll to your projects section, you may want to take a look at that code as well.

Hope this helps